# Does the set.seed() function in combination with the sample() function provides always the same sample independent of the used hardware?

Tags: r, sample

I ran the `sample()` command in combination with the `set.seed()` command to obtain always the same sample and everything worked fine. However, applying the same commands on a different laptop gave back a different sample. Does anyone have any idea what has happened?

I tried also the combination `set.seed()` and `rnorm()`, surprisingly I got then exactly the same random numbers on both laptops.

```
set.seed(123)
sample(LETTERS,6)

set.seed(123)
rnorm(6,1,1)
```

I expected that on both laptops the result "H" "T" "J" "U" "W" "A" is displayed. However, one laptop displayed the result "O" "S" "N" "C" "J" "R".

```
set.seed(123)
rnorm(6,1,1)
```

produced

```
0.4395244 0.7698225 2.5587083 1.0705084 1.1292877 2.7150650
```

on both laptops.

Comment: Both machines are running with the same R version 3.6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not due to cross-hardware reproducibility issues, but a difference introduced in R 3.6.0 -- you must have one machine on R 3.6.0 and the other on an earlier version. From `help("set.seed")` (from R 3.6.0):

> Usage
>
> ...
>   set.seed(seed, kind = NULL, normal.kind = NULL, sample.kind = NULL)
>   ...
>
> Details
>
> sample.kind can be "Rounding" or "Rejection", or partial matches to
>   these. The former was the default in versions prior to 3.6.0: it made
>   sample noticeably non-uniform on large populations, and should only be
>   used for reproduction of old results. See PR#17494 for a discussion.

Observe the following to see the difference *within* machine (i.e., this shows it is not a cross-hardware issue, because I'm doing this on only one machine):

```
set.seed(123, sample.kind = "Rejection") # Default in R 3.6.0
sample(LETTERS, 6)
# [1] "O" "S" "N" "C" "J" "R"

set.seed(123, sample.kind = "Rounding") # Default in R < 3.6.0
sample(LETTERS, 6)
# [Warning omitted]
# [1] "H" "T" "J" "U" "W" "A"
```

Comment: Great, this solved my problem. I just adjusted the sample.kind option. Thank you for your help!